# Automatically updating input field with same id using javascipt/jquery once user enter value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql

I have an SQL table that looks like this:

| No | Task | ClusterID | Assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Walk dog out | 1.1.1 |  |
| 2 | Walk cat out | 1.1.1 |  |
| 3 | Go Groceries | 1.1.2 |  |
| 4 | Go veterinar | 1.1.2 |  |

Then I query the sql question table into form in while loop using php and append ClusterID as id in input field:

```
<td style="overflow-x: hidden; width: 90px">
  <a style="display: none">'.$Assessment.'</a>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend"></div>

    <input
      type="number"
      id="cluster'.$ClusterID.'"
      name="selfRating[]"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      value="'.$Assessment.'"
      class="form-control"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
    />
  </div>
</td>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, whenever a user enters a value into the input field that has the same id, other input fields with the same id will automatically fill. How can I do this using javascript or jquery?

For example, the user enters a value for question No 1, then No 2 will automatically be filled with the same value as what the user put in question No 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same ids for mutliple elements . Instead use data-attribute i.e : `data-id="cluster'.$ClusterID.'"` and when user type in input-box use `$("input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").val(value)` to update same values to other inputs with same data-id .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("[name*=selfRating]").on("keyup change", function() {
  var data_id = $(this).data("id"); //get data id
  var value = $(this).val() //get value which user typed
  $("input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").val(value) //assign to other inputs as well with same data-id
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow-x: hidden;width: 90px;">
      <a style="display:none;">abc</a>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
        </div>
        <!--use data-id="cluster'.$ClusterID.'"-->
        <input type="number" data-id="cluster1" name="selfRating[]" min="0" max="10" value="abc" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow-x: hidden;width: 90px;">
      <a style="display:none;">abc2</a>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
        </div>

        <input type="number" data-id="cluster1" name="selfRating[]" min="0" max="10" value="abc2" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow-x: hidden;width: 90px;">
      <a style="display:none;">abc22</a>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
        </div>

        <input type="number" data-id="cluster2" name="selfRating[]" min="0" max="10" value="abc22" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow-x: hidden;width: 90px;">
      <a style="display:none;">abc23</a>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
        </div>

        <input type="number" data-id="cluster3" name="selfRating[]" min="0" max="10" value="abc23" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="overflow-x: hidden;width: 90px;">
      <a style="display:none;">abc23</a>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
        </div>

        <input type="number" data-id="cluster3" name="selfRating[]" min="0" max="10" value="abc23" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```